# Uncaught ReferenceError: '' is not defined

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, partial-views, viewrendering

Using: VS'12, asp.net MVC4 Internet Application, MVC, EF Code First + Kendo UI

***Error***

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: filterCountys is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

*However* It is defined ... ???

[image]

*I'm unsure if it makes a difference but this code is in a PartialView called from an Ajax Script*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the scripts back to the main View, they must be on your Index View( the Main View ) not the Partial View. This is why there not showing up correctly.

I'm not certain for the reason but if i'd guess. Your partial either isn't loading in the scripts or they must be available from the Main / Index View.